# How do I call a parent method with a different name than the one I am in?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mootools

I want to call `[Parent].f()` from within `[Child].g()` rather than `[Child].f()`.

Suppose I have the MooTools code:

```
var Parent = new Class({
    f: function () {
        console.log('Parent.f()');
    }
});

var Child = new Class({
    Extends: Parent,

    f: function () {
        console.log('Child.f()');
    },

    g: function () {
        // Call Parent.f()
        this.parent.f();
    }
});

var o = new Child();

o.g();
```

Obviously `this.parent.f()` is nonsense because MooTools makes `this.parent` to be the parent class's method with the same name as the method you are in, i.e. in `Child.g()` this would be `Parent.g()`.

So, how can I call `P.f()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Child` `hasOwnProperty` `f`, so calling `child.f()` will get it on the instance and not the prototype.

Rather than hack with switching `this.$caller.$name` as suggested in a different answer, just call it from the parent prototype direct:

```
this.$constructor.parent.prototype.f.call(this);
// or
this.$constructor.parent.prototype.f.apply(this, arguments);
```

Of course, if you don't care about Reflection-ish, you can just do `P.prototype.f.call(this)` - but it is non-DRY as it means the method needs to know the name of the super.

The problem with this approach is if it will work if Parent is extending another parent and so on but it should be fine for most cases. It will also fail if Child has no parent or no `f`, where it should logically revert to running its own implementation of `f`.

```
var Parent = new Class({
    f: function(msg){
        console.log('Parent.f() says ' + msg);
    }
});

var Child = new Class({
    Extends: Parent,
    f: function(){
        console.log('Child.f()');
    },   
    g: function(){
        // Call Parent.f()
        this.$constructor.parent.prototype.f.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

new Child().g('hello');
```

If you need to do this often, you can create a new method on your parent classes as a mixin. eg.

```
Class.parenting = new Class({
    // mixin class that allows call
    _parent: function(method, args){
        this.$constructor.parent.prototype[method].apply(this, args);    
    }.protect() // private, restricted to methods
});

var Parent = new Class({
    Implements: [Class.parenting],
    f: function(msg){
        console.log('Parent.f() says ' + msg);
    }
});

var Child = new Class({
    Extends: Parent,
    f: function(){
        console.log('Child.f()');
    },   
    g: function(){
        this._parent('f', arguments);
    }
});

var c = new Child();
c.g('hello');
c._parent('f'); // throws, only instances methods can call this
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty quick and nasty way to do it found by looking at the MooTools code, however it may break on newer versions of MooTools.

It works by setting `this.$caller.$name` to the method you want to call and resetting it after the call.

```
    g: function () {
         var oldName = this.$caller.$name;
         this.$caller.$name = 'f';

         try {
             this.parent(...);
         } catch (e) {
             this.$caller.$name = oldName; // Ensure name is always reset
             throw e;
         }

         this.$caller.$name = oldName;
     }
```